# Are all squared metric distances also divergences?

Tags: statistics, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a differentiable manifold that is also a [metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Definition) $(M,d)$, equipped with the topology induced by the metric distance $d$; further, assume that $d$ is $C^2$ on $M\times M$. Now, let $D:M\times M\to[0,+\infty )$ be the squared metric distance, i.e. $D(p,q):=(d(p,q))^2$.

Is it true that $D$ is also a [divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_(statistics)#Definition)?

Non-negativity and positivity are trivial but I can't prove that

> For every $p\in M$, $D(p,p+dp)$ is a positive-definite quadratic form for infinitesimal displacements $dp$ from $p$.

This holds by definition if the manifold is a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ and $d$ is the geodesic distance induced by $g$. In general, though, I can only prove that the quadratic form is positive-semidefinite (as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_(statistics)#Geometrical_properties)).

Comment: To make your question sensible you probably want some extra hypotheses in order to avoid boring counterexamples. For instance, there are boring counterexamples where the topology generated by $d$ is not the manifold topology, and where the topology generated by $d$ *is* the manifold topology but $d$ does not satisfy the smoothness hypothesis of a divergence...

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for the input! I've tried to improve the question. What do you think?